# Blazor Scaffold Items such as Login.cshtml files nothing at the address when published but works on local host

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a blazor web application that currently works fine locally on localhost. When I run the application in Visual studio it checks if the user is authorized or not and redirects to the login page. The login page is a scaffolded item I added in and tweaked the look of page the page and its still called login.cshtml in the path: /Identity/Account/Login.

When I run the code locally - and click the link it redirects perfectly fine:

```
   <a id="login" href="/Identity/Account/Login">Login</a>
```

This is the local link  https://localhost:44321/Identity/Account/Login (Worked fine)

I have published this blazor application to Azure Linux by right clicking on publish. Once it is published successfully it takes me directly to the "Sorry, there's nothing at this address."
(https://myblazorappname.azurewebsites.net/Identity/Account/Login)

All the .razor pages seem to work perfectly fine when published. But the .cshtml files are having issues. The forgotton password scaffolded item is the same issue.

Default.razor - This is the first .razor page it goes to and based on authorization it takes you either to Authors.razor if your already logged in otherwise i would like it to take me to Login.cshtml.

As I mentioned this works perfectly fine locally on debug mode on visual studio.

```
@page "/"
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager


<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <Authors /> -- WORKS FINE
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>

        <a id="login" href="/Identity/Account/Login">Login</a> -- DOSENT WORK (Login.cshtml)
        <a id="forgot-password" href="/Identity/Account/ForgotPassword">Forgot password?</a> -- DOESNT WORK

        <a href="authors">Go to authors</a> -- WORKS FINE (Authors.Razor)

        @*<RedirectToLogin />*@
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>


@code {


}
```

When it loads i get the following error and dont know how to debug this:

[image]

Am i missing something here?

Comment: Did you check your Azure log ? You probably have the issue in log

Comment: Azure logs pointed out the code was using a windows syntax on a linux box